# How to set an OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-intent, onitemclicklistener

I have a listview of items. Now i want to build an OnItemClickListener. If the user clicked on the item, a new actvity starts. The Actvity give a ArrayList with imagePaths over the put.Extra Methode, to load pictures on the same place. But if i clicked on item, the different pictures are loading. Here ist the code

```
MyCompositionView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        int count = 0;
        ArrayList<String> tmpImgPath = new ArrayList<String>();
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
                count++;


                for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                    tmpImgPath.add(myList.get(i).imgPath.get(j));
                }

            }

            if (count == 3) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MyCompositionsListActivity.this, LayoutForThreeActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("imgPaths", tmpImgPath);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

I think something is wrong with my for loop!

Comment: What's the meaning of your loop?

Comment: The first loop, goes through the all items at the list, and the second loop goes throgh an ArrayList<String> and read paths to the images for each iteam at the list

Comment: Why do you need count++;?

Comment: i think, count ist wrong on this place, i need to work with position right?

Answer (score 0):

```
MyCompositionView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    int count = 0;
    ArrayList<String> tmpImgPath = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
           // count++;


            //for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
               // tmpImgPath.add(myList.get(i).imgPath.get(j));
            //}

        //}

       // if (count == 3) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyCompositionsListActivity.this, LayoutForThreeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("imgPaths", myList.get(position).imgPath);
            startActivity(intent);
       // }
    }
});
```